# Calculating height of view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UICollectionView` subclass which I'm trying to embed into a `UITableView` Row. It already works, but I can't manage to calculate the correct height.Here's how I'm doing it:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  if indexPath.row==2{
    if(self.contentViewCell == nil){
      self.contentViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Storyboard.containerCellIdentifier)
      let matchDetailView = getMatchDetailView()
      matchDetailView.frame = self.contentViewCell!.contentView.frame
      self.contentViewCell!.contentView.addSubview(matchDetailView)
    }

    self.contentViewCell?.layoutIfNeeded()
    let size = self.contentViewCell?.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingExpandedSize)
    return size!.height + 1
  }
  return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Unfortunately the height is always wrong. Can anyone point me to the right direction please?

It needs to work on iOS 7 as well.

EDIT:

`getMatchDetailView()` instantiates the ViewController from the storyboard and returns it's view.

Comment: Have you used `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` ?

Comment: `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is not available on iOS 7

Comment: reload the collectionview in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: @Nishant you mean I should reload the child collectionview in the `viewDidAppear`function of my tableviewcontroller? How would that make sense? I need to return the correct height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` - reloading the collectionView wouldn't have any effect

Comment: @gasparuff Are u using autolayout? if yes, `self.contentViewCell!.contentView.frame` might not return correct value untill `viewDidLoad`

Comment: You mean until `viewDidAppear`? Because `viewDidLoad` is the first function, that gets called. Yes, I'm using AutoLayout

Comment: @gasparuff: Sorry, typo. Yes I mean `viewDidAppear`. Let me know if it works or not.